# Why is Twin Peaks rated so highly by critics?

Tags: twin-peaks

I don't want this to just sound like an opinion thread, I just want to know if there was more to the TV show than what I interpreted.

I've just finished the first series of Twin Peaks, and I can't seem to understand why it's rated so highly around the internet.

[IMDB, for example, gives it 9/10](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098936/), whilst [Metacritic scores it at 96/100](http://www.metacritic.com/tv/twin-peaks).

I can understand it having a "cult" following and it being a classic but the show just doesn't seem to have anything going for it apart from too many characters.

Can anyone give any evidence to why it's regarded as such a good TV show?

Comment: At the time there was literally *nothing* else like it.  TV back then was *very* different...

Comment: Because in the era before premium cable television shows, broadcast network television was *bleak*. At the time, newspaper editorials were all up in arms about how over the top Twin Peaks was (quite tame by today's standards). In such an environment, any show that could do that would attract a cult following.

Comment: Because the owls are not what they seem. I agree with @JimmyShelter -- there was literally nothing like it on television at the time. I think it faltered badly after Laura Palmer's death was solved because Who Killed Laura Palmer was the sole reason for the existence of the show. After the killer was revealed, there had been nothing further, plot-wise, set up to carry the show. It appealed to a quirky (in the good way) audience and David Lynch fans. *Twins Peaks* is the best TV soundtrack ever -- it's a must have. I named my iPad "Diane" after Agent Cooper's tape recorder :)

Comment: @JohnO Oh, that's it.. maybe I won't bother with season 2 as I thought it may get interesting.

Comment: @Slytherincess Yeah after I found out the killer I wasn't keen on carrying on with it! but yes, I do like the music in Twin Peaks :) .. and Cooper

Comment: @Slytherincess: I can’t wait until I can re-name Siri “Diane”.

Comment: @Adsy: I think season 2 is still worth watching. There are a couple of images from it that absolutely terrify me. Specifically on IMDB giving it 9 out of 10, that’s an average from 69,953 user ratings, so the explanation for that is simply that about 70,000 people really like it, and rated it on IMDB. It’s very tricky to explain why people like the things they like.

Comment: @JohnO: I think your comment deserves to be expanded into an answer.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I answered as a courtesy... I'm not sure that it's even on-topic. The answer is more about the general culture of the United States in the 1990s. If someone else wants to expand on my comment, they're welcome to the rep.

Comment: @JohnO - That's also a weighted average. Around 10% of the voters rated it 5 stars or less, (5/10) with 6% of those only rating it 1 star. While it was popular, it wasn't universal, and solving the murder in the middle of the 2nd season led to a very quick decline in ratings (Hence the sudden cancellation).

Comment: @Slytherincess - I don't think it was Laura Palmer; round my way it was coffee (damn fine), cherry pie, logs and all the quirky goings on that made it appealing; Laura Palmer was just an excuse in the background for the other stuff to exist.  In the second season it started taking itself too seriously with the occult stuff and lost much of it's charm and appeal.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - *"Nobody loved Laura but us."* Let me clarify. All the quirkiness and kitsch underlying Laura's murder was not enough for *the average Nielsen watcher* to hold their viewership once the murder was solved. Ratings plummeted and subsequently *Twin Peaks* was axed. All I'm saying is from a detached, logical perspective, I understand this dynamic. As a die hard *Twin Peaks* fan, I would've *blissfully* lived on a steady diet of *Twin Peaks* quips and oddities for many more years -- Harry, that goes without saying. Now, off to practice Audrey's dance ... :)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Yes! That would be awesome! I've come across a few people who have named their gadgets "Diane" and it's like a special secret handshake or something --delightful! All my computers and gadgets are named after Harry Potter characters, except for Diane my iPad :)

Comment: @JohnO: I see your point. I think questions about a show’s reception (either with critics or the public) can be on-topic though — [the help page on asking questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically mentions questions about the “historical or societal context of a work”.

Comment: @Slytherincess just out of curiosity, as I know I won't watch series 2, who or what is Diane? is it an actually person or just Cooper's voice recorder name?

Comment: @Adsy - we never really find out.  That's part of why some of us older hands find modern expectations a little frustrating - we weren't always guaranteed to be told or shown everything, and we just accepted that because it was normal.

Comment: @Adsy: Diane is (I think — must look up references for all this) intended to be Agent Cooper’s assistant back in Washington DC.

Comment: Becasue it is awesome.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yea, I assumed from the first time he said "Diane" that it would be some sort of assistant/secretary of Coopers

Comment: @Adsy -- I've always thought Diane was Agent Cooper's little handheld tape recorder, but perhaps the tape recorder is just an incidental device that serves as a means of communication to a real-life assistant named Diane back in DC. I never really thought about it -- just assumed! I'm no expert -- just a fan -- and admittedly it's been several years since I re-watched the series. Perhaps someone with more knowledge will let us know for certain. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Well I assumed he was just talking to to tape recorder and refering to Diane as she may listen to the tapes at a later date herself. That's what I just thought from the first episode.

Comment: @Slytherincess: I believe in the second series Diane does at least arrange for Coop to view a property in Twin Peaks with a view to purchasing it.

Comment: @SaturnsEye: “who is Diane?” We get to meet her — well, kind of — in *Twin Peaks: The Return*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Regarding the IMDB rating, that’s (at time of writing) an average of 69,953 user ratings. So, quite simply, about 70,000 people really like it, and rated it on IMDB.

As to why IMDB users like it, it’s a bit speculative, but IMDB is popular within the movie and TV production community (as people who work in the industry can use it, to some extent, to promote themselves). Twin Peaks may appeal to them because it includes elements that satirise television itself.

The multitude of characters you refer to, along with the melodramatic tone and certain plot elements of the show (Identical cousins! Doe-eyed teenagers in love! Murky local business dealings! Almost every married person having an affair!), and the fact that it’s a serialised and continuous story, are meant to imitate and satirise American TV soap operas. You may have noticed that the show even includes its own fictional soap opera, *[Invitation to Love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Peaks#Invitation_to_Love)*.

*Twin Peaks* was partially intended as a dark and disturbing parody of soap operas, to fit with Lynch’s perennial theme of revealing the darkness lurking underneath the bland and glossy surface of suburban America. Being a parody of a much-looked-down-on genre of TV, whilst having very high production values, may appeal to people who work in the industry, as they’re primed to be aware of the aspects of soap operas being parodied.

Apart from that (and unfortunately I can’t find the interview where I read this tidbit right now), I believe Lynch has discussed how he received effusive letters from survivors of domestic abuse after the second season aired, as dark events happening in suburbia aren’t often shown on mainstream American TV. ([One such fan](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2015/may/29/how-twin-peaks-fan-trouble-northwest-passage) Kickstarted a *Twin Peaks* documentary about his experiences.)

I don’t think that has much bearing on the *general* high esteem in which the show is held, but it’s an interesting point about how fictional works can resonate very strongly with some people, whilst passing others by entirely.

Comment: I like that you discussed David Lynch's penchant for pulling back the curtain, so to speak, and exposing the darkness that lurks behind typical sunny facades. Regarding dysfunctional relationships, the infamous line of dialogue *"I'd rather be his wh*re than your wife"* is always attributed to Kate Winslet's character, Rose, on *Titanic* in 1997, but it was Norma Jennings who first said it to Hank Jennings on *Twin Peaks* in 1990-1991. Anyhow, +1 :)

Comment: @Slytherincess: nice, I hadn’t noticed that. Twin Peaks: so far ahead of its time. Yeah I saw *Blue Velvet* after the first season of Twin Peaks, cut from similar cloth.